# What happen to upload mission when screen is off?

Tags: android

Anybody now what happening if I try to upload files using background service, for example using the HttpClient java object, and the screen is turned off while the upload in progress?

When the device screen turn off (after 30 sec for example), the background service stopped?

I test it on my Samsung Galaxy SII, and the upload continue to run, even when the screen is off, but I don't know what happen in other devices.

Comment: What **upload mission** ? Whirrr click....whirr click... houston we've got a problem...

Comment: upload mission using HttpClient java object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running it on a background service, it'll continue to upload when the screen is turned off. Services started aren't stopped until stopService is explicitly called.

Comment: Yes, but what happened to the data connection, are you sure that the Wifi and data keep working when the screen turned off?

Comment: If it truly is running in a `Service`, yes.